# AngularJS Directive to check if an image URL exist

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to write an AngularJS Directive that checks if a URL exist, if it does then it will display the image. Otherwise it will return nothing or a blank  tag. Any advice would be appreciated, here's the fiddle I have so far, can't seem to get it to even read the url being passed in.
http://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/dXeap/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only be able to this with images on the same domain as it would violate cross-domain policy otherwise. If that is still ok then it should be possible by using AJAX to do a HEAD request and checking the HTTP status (e.g. 404) of the response.

I fixed up your code a bit so that it works. http://jsfiddle.net/LwpEP/1/
See how you get on from that starting point and come back here if you run into more issues.

Comment: Thanks Daveyjoe, I was ultimately trying to create a directive for a presence indicator, so the data passed in would be like "online", "offline", "away". So my directive will display a red, yellow, or green image. Could you do a jsfiddle example of that? :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to relate to your original question. If this is a new question then perhaps it would make more sense to create a new question on StackOverflow.